What is this radio antenna connector called?
I have this radio antenna, and need to replace the coaxial cable, but cannot figure out what this connection is called?

Some more clues please - what kind of antenna is it, where is it installed, what frequency range, etc?

That will be impossible to say for sure without taking a few measurements (mostly: outer thread diameter and inner conductor diameter; also, the cable type attached to it, if possible), but I don't think it's "reverse gender F connector" (which AFAIK isn't a thing). It looks pretty nonstandard to me, and Andrea's Identiconn tool wasn't helping me, either

(Did I mention Identiconn? It's really cool, you click on Coax, then enable the filters. In your case, you filter for something that a) connects to coax cable b) has a shrouded female connector c) has threads as fastening type. you get a few things, but none look like yours; Identiconn certainly isn't complete (it can't possibly know all possible RF connectors), but if your connector's not in there, buying it commercially might become hard)

This looks like an F connector, commonly used for TV antennas, and probably 75 ohms.
The male end typically uses the solid center conductor of RG6 or RG59 as its center pin.

You just might be right! An F with the gender reversed. I've never seen one like this, though.

The bottom one looks like a normal F to me.  The top one has an extra collar and the hole size is suspicious, but it still looks like an F.  Can't tell if the collar has threads, but if it doesn't, it's well within the variation of F connectors.
